# Searchable MultiSelect or the best approach

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

Users of a report have requested the ability to be able to manually enter a code, currently they are are presented a multiselect with all the codes related to the previous parameters.

**This is in Report Builder 3.**

This multiselect can become quite long so I thought another approach would be a searchable multiselect. Is this possible in any: way, shape, or form?

Could I allow for a cascading parameter (which is the code) to be either selected either through manual typing or another means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add a type-in text parameter (lets call it Search_Code), with a default of % (assuming your data source is SQL).

Then in the data source for the Code list, I would add to the WHERE clause e.g.

`WHERE Code LIKE '%' + @Search_Code + '%'`

This will restrict the Code list to strings which partially match the Search_Code value (if entered).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. 
I actually ended up doing something like this and it works great. Thanks Mike.